# Getting content from current tab (AjaxTabbedPanel)

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabs, wicket

I'm doing some tests on a wicket prototype here, and I got stuck on this little issue.

I have an AjaxTabbedPanel within a page, with 5 tabs. It's working ok so far but I'd like to add some behavior BEFORE the new tab request has been processed (e.g do some validation and storing something on session before the tab changes).

AjaxTabbedPanel let me override the **onAjaxUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target)** but this one takes place AFTER the new tab has been set. I'd need something like "beforeAjaxRequest".

Is there any way of doing this without changing things around too much? (Sticking with AjaxTabbedPanel, no JS, etc). You might think "why don't you load the whole page at once and navigate with JS tabs", but I'm trying to work on a native wicket tab solution for now (there are reasons for that).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the newLink(String linkId, final int index); method. Thats what an AjaxTabbedPanel does when it extends TabbedPanel to add the ajax behaviour http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/wicket/wicket-extensions/1.2/wicket-extensions-1.2-sources.jar!/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/tabs/AjaxTabbedPanel.java?format=ok.

You could set up the newlink so it uses the same code as the ajaxtabbedpanel but adds a validation clause so when a user clicks it, it validates first and then decides whether to change the tab and update.

Hope that helps.